# How to call Control-M API's using Postman?

Tags: postman, control-m

I have been trying to use the Control-M API documentation provided by BMC, and I am unable successfully invoke an API call to it.

When tried to first provide the login credentials using `/login` resource to get the `apiKey` which I could use for further resource calls, I get a variety of Error Responses. i.e. `405 method not allowed` while using `POST`, and `404 Page not found` while using `GET`. At this point I am not sure if there is some problem with Control-M API version(9.20.105), or am I using the correct endpoint (CTRLM URL)?

> is is not possible via postman?
> Note: I am not sure if I am allowed to paste my clients URL here.

I would be really helpful if someone could illustrate a live Control-M API call which is publicly available to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an installation of Control-M with automation API you can use its swagger as reference.
Given a Control-M installed on a host named myControlM you should be able to browse to:
`https://myControlM:8443/automation-api`